# How can I determine when my application is about to be terminated in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

When my application is moved into the background, I'd like to be able to detect when it is about to be terminated (for memory exhaustion or other reasons).  Is there a way to do this?

In particular, is there a way to execute some code before the application is terminated when in the background?

Comment: Why voted to close? This seems a good question to me.

Comment: @WTP should've seen it before the heroic edit by Brad :)

Comment: @Michael Stum: actually, that comment is older than the edit. Some grammatical errors really don't matter to me. If it's clear what's being asked, it's awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in the [`-[<UIApplicationDelegate> applicationWillTerminate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method of your application delegate, like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [database save]; // or whatever you want to do
}
```

This will be executed whenever the app is about to be terminated, unless it crashes.

Comment: This is not true for applications that are suspended in the background.  From the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW10): "If your application is currently suspended, the system kills your application and removes it from memory without any notice."  You will only receive this callback if your application is actively running code in the background.

Comment: @Brad Larson Then you should execute code to save data in `-[<UIApplicationDelegate> applicationDidEnterBackground:]` or I won't see another way. This is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to do whatever cleanup needs to be done in your application (saving state or user data, etc.) as your application transitions into the background.  If your application is suspended, you will not have a chance to perform any last code before it is terminated by the system.

From the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW10):

> If your application is running (either
>   in the foreground or background) at
>   termination time, the system calls
>   your application delegate’s
>   applicationWillTerminate: method so
>   that you can perform any required
>   cleanup. You can use this method to
>   save user data or application state
>   information that you would use to
>   restore your application to its
>   current state on a subsequent launch.
>   Your method implementation has
>   approximately 5 seconds to perform any
>   tasks and return. If it does not
>   return in time, the application is
>   killed and removed from memory. The
>   applicationWillTerminate: method is
>   not called if your application is
>   currently suspended.
>
> Even if you develop your application
>   using iOS SDK 4 and later, you must
>   still be prepared for your application
>   to be killed without any notification.
>   The user can kill applications
>   explicitly using the multitasking UI.
>   In addition, if memory becomes
>   constrained, the system might remove
>   applications from memory to make more
>   room. If your application is currently
>   suspended, the system kills your
>   application and removes it from memory
>   without any notice. However, if your
>   application is currently running in
>   the background state (in other words,
>   not suspended), the system calls the
>   applicationWillTerminate: method of
>   your application delegate. Your
>   application cannot request additional
>   background execution time from this
>   method.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you mean getting notification while your application is suspended in the background, there is no way to know; the `applicationWillTerminate:` method is not run if you're suspended. The recommended approach is to save any required state when you get the `applicationWillEnterBackground:` message, so that if you get killed in the background you're ready to start up again.

If you're actually in an "executing in the background" state, (which can happen briefly after exiting the app or if the app has requested temporary background execution time,) then `applicationWillTerminate:` *will* be called just like you'd expect.

Comment: According to Apple, this is not correct. If your application has entered background processing, it will receive applicationWillTerminate if the user or OS needs to terminate it (see Brad Larsons answer which quotes the Apple docs).

Comment: I guess that's true; there's a distinction between "backgrounded" and "suspended" which I did not address. I'll fix that.